# Generate time list from query with date range and multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

Struggling to get my head round a complicated SQL query.

Here's a sqlfiddle with the tables/data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7de65

Might make more sense if I explain what the tables are doing;

schedules is a list of train schedules, calling is a list of calling points for that schedule ordered as the train will pass them, activations are created when it's confirmed the train is going to run<sup>1</sup> and a movement is created as the train moves over a specified calling point.

calling is associated with schedules via the calling.sid. activations are associated with schedules via activations.sid. movement is associated with activations via movement.activation, and with calling via movement.calling_id.

Now the actual problem;

I want to generate a list of trains active per minute. A train is considered active if

- It has at least 1 movement associated with it's activation (I.E. has not left it's origin)
- It does not have a movement associated with it's final calling point
- It was activated less than 24 hours ago

A train should always be considered active if all of these criteria are met, so listed in the count.

With the data in the above sqlfiddle, a train leaves it's first calling point at 14:20 and arrives at it's last calling point at 15:04, it should be included in the count for every minute from 14:20-15:04. I'm wondering if someone could shed some light on how to do this. I wouldn't consider myself a SQL expert (probably why I'm struggling, I wouldn't actually consider myself vaguely competent but that's a different issue, or maybe the same, I'm not sure).

I've started going down this sort of line

```
SELECT
    YEAR( activations.activated ),
    MONTH( activations.activated ),
    DAY( activations.activated ),
    HOUR( activations.activated ),
    MINUTE( activations.activated ),
    count(activations.id)
FROM activations, movement, calling, schedules 
WHERE activations.id = movement.activation AND movement.calling_id = calling.id AND schedules.id = activations.sid
GROUP BY DAYOFYEAR( activations.activated ) , HOUR( activations.activated ), MINUTE(activations.activated )
```

But I know that's wrong, because a train will only be listed once however long it's activated.

I also thought about doing it directly in Python with a loop for each minute of the specified period, and it sort of works like that but it's super slow (getting active trains at a minute resolution over 24 hours results in 1440 queries, not exactly optimized). So I'm thinking it ether has to be some clever grouping, or some sort of loop within SQL, but I have no idea how to do ether.

So if I ran the query for 14:18 through to 15:07 I would get something like

```
+-----------------+------------------+
| Timestamp       | Active services  |
+-----------------+------------------+
| 14:18 1/1/2014  | 0                |
| 14:19 1/1/2014  | 0                |
| 14:20 1/1/2014  | 1                |
| 14:21 1/1/2014  | 1                |
| 14:22 1/1/2014  | 1                |
[...
Identical record for every minute through to
    ...]
| 15:03 1/1/2014  | 1                |
| 15:04 1/1/2014  | 1                |
| 15:05 1/1/2014  | 0                |
| 15:06 1/1/2014  | 0                |
| 15:07 1/1/2014  | 0                |
+-----------------+------------------+
```

(Format of the time stamp is not important so long as I can parse it later)

In my head, I can see it sort of working like this (pseudocode)

```
while time is between report_start_date and report_end_date:
    records = count(
        activations where number of movements(
            movement.actual < time
        ) > 0 //Number of movements created before current minute
            and
        movement.calling_id = calling_points(
            actual < minute
        ).last.id does not exist //As of this minute doesn't have a movement for last calling point
            and
        activations.activated > now - 24 hours //Was activated less than 24 hours ago
    )
    result timestamp, records
    time + 1 minute
```

I've pretty much got the records = count() bit sorted, it's just ether looping over or grouping by time I'm not sure about. I can group by the date of the first movement record but again the record will only show for the first minute. I want it to show for every minute it's active for.

---

#### Bonus points

I'm actually trying to implement this in SQLAlchemy (hence the tag), I'm trying to get the basics working in SQL before moving it into a SQLAlchemy query but if you can do it in SQL *and* SQLAlchemy/Python you'll get something, I'm not quite sure what yet and it may be hypothetical.

---

1. Before anyone who actually knows about this stuff criticizes me, an activation doesn't *confirm* a train will run, but it's close enough for my current purposes. My final query will exclude cancellations and stuff but I'm just trying to get the basics down first.

Comment: @Strawberry Sure, I've just included the main fields I think will be relevant.

Comment: Great, now extending that idea, consider providing proper DDLs of the simplified schema (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. That way, we can more easily understand what you're talking about!

Comment: @Strawberry Added a SQLFiddle instead and (hopefully) clarified the result I'm expecting back. It's a stripped back dataset excluding the interim calling points and movements, just the first and last. I've also added some pseudocode to sort of show what I'm trying to do in my head.

Comment: Not knowing the model of the business, few things are unclear to me:
1. what is the Train ID: is there a separate model or is it `trustid`?
2. how does one know what what is a `starting` point and what is `final` point?
Your example has only two and one can infer by time, but I assume there are schedules
with multiple ones, so does the query need to figure out also the last one by
the time? or by the fact that there is only ARRIVAL in there?

Comment: @van A train and an `activation` are the same, `trustid` is an ID for an external service but it can be used to uniquely identify a train. A query for `calling` ordered by `calling.id` will return the calling points in order, most services have many calling points. You can't use the time to order them since a train might leave origin at 23:30 and arrive at destination at 00:30. SQLFiddle would only allow me to put in a small amount of data, here's the full calling list for that schedule http://i.imgur.com/hDyjcN4.png

Comment: @van `movement` links to `calling` via `movement.calling_id`, so one can reference a calling point from a movement but it needs to determine when a `movement` corresponds to the last calling point for a `schedule`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate some result for every possible minute, I would not rely on the fact that every possible minute is a value in some table in the database. For this reason I would actually create a "static" table in the database which would only store those timestamps, and we would construct a query starting from there. I have done the following:

```
CREATE TABLE "static_time" (
    "yyyymmddhhmm" datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("yyyymmddhhmm")
);
```

*NOTE: for all the tests I used `sqlite` database, so you might need to change in some places to use corresponsing `mysql` constructs.*

I also added all the data for the period of 2 days for testing. You should probably do the same for period from when you want to run the first analysis to some big year in the future (for example: `2050-12-31T23:59:00`). I did this using `sqlalchemy`, but i am sure it would make sense to do this directly using some function or a loop:

```
class StaticTime(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'static_time'
    __table_args__ = ({'autoload': True, },)

# ...

def populate_static_time():
    print "Adding static times"
    sdt = datetime(2014, 1, 1)
    edt = sdt + timedelta(days=2)
    cdt = sdt
    while cdt <= edt:
        session.add(StaticTime(yyyymmddhhmm = cdt))
        cdt += timedelta(minutes=1)
    session.commit()
populate_static_time()
```

Further I assumed your SA model including defined relationships as per below:

```
# MODEL
class Schedule(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'schedules'
    __table_args__ = ({'autoload': True, },)


class Calling(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'calling'
    __table_args__ = ({'autoload': True, },)


class Activation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'activations'
    __table_args__ = ({'autoload': True, },)

    # relationships:
    schedule = relationship("Schedule")


class Movement(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'movement'
    __table_args__ = ({'autoload': True, },)

    # relationships:
    # @note: use activation_rel as activation is column name
    activation_rel = relationship("Activation", backref="movements")
```

**Now, lets build the query:**

```
# 0. start with all times and proper counting (columns in SELECT)
q = session.query(
        StaticTime.yyyymmddhhmm.label("yyyymmddhhmm"),
        func.count(Activation.id.distinct()).label("count"),
    )

# 1. join on the trains which are active (or finished, which will be excluded later)
q = q.filter(Activation.movements.any(Movement.actual < StaticTime.yyyymmddhhmm))

# 2. join on the trains which are not finished (or no rows for those that did not)
# 2.a) subquery to get the "last" calling per sid
last_calling_sqry = (session.query(
        Calling.sid.label("sid"),
        func.max(Calling.id).label("max_calling_id"),
    )
    .group_by(Calling.sid)
).subquery("xxx")

# 2.b) subquery to find the movement for the "last" colling
train_done_at_sqry = (session.query(
        Activation.id.label("activation_id"),
        Movement.actual.label("arrived_time"),
    )
    .join(last_calling_sqry, Activation.sid == last_calling_sqry.c.sid)
    .join(Movement, and_(
            Movement.calling_id == last_calling_sqry.c.max_calling_id,
            Movement.activation == Activation.id,
        ))
).subquery("yyy")

# 2.c) lets use it now
q = q.outerjoin(train_done_at_sqry,
        train_done_at_sqry.c.activation_id == Activation.id,
    )
# 2.d) only those that arrived "after" currently tested time
q = q.filter(train_done_at_sqry.c.arrived_time >= StaticTime.yyyymmddhhmm)


# 3. add filter to use only those trains that started in last 24 hours
# @note: do not need this in case when step-X is used as well as it filters
# @TODO: replace func.date(...) with MYSQL version
q = q.filter(Activation.activated >= func.date("now", "-1 days"))

# 4. filter and group by
q = q.group_by(StaticTime.yyyymmddhhmm)
q = q.order_by(StaticTime.yyyymmddhhmm)

# @NOTE: at this point "q" will return only those minutes which have at least 1 active train

# X. FINALLY: WRAP AGAIN TO HAVE ALL MINUTES (also those with no active trains)
sub = q.subquery("sub")
w = session.query(
        StaticTime.yyyymmddhhmm.label("Timestamp"),
        func.ifnull(sub.c.count, 0).label("Active Services")
        )
w = w.outerjoin(sub, sub.c.yyyymmddhhmm == StaticTime.yyyymmddhhmm)
# @TODO: replace func.date(...) with MYSQL version
w = w.filter(Activation.activated >= func.date("now", "-1 days"))

for a in w:
    print a
```

This is a rather complicated query, and given only the data that you provided, it is very difficult to test different scenarios. But hopefully you would be able to compare to your current results and the code will give you some hints on how this could be done. Also, i might have joined on wrong columns in some places (`actual` vs `planned`). Again, this will probably not work on the mysql (I do not have it and do not know it very well).

**Bonus (*reversed*):** the SQL statement generated by the `w` query for `sqlite`. You might find it easier to start with raw `SQL` and gradually move towards `sqlalchemy`.

```
SELECT static_time.yyyymmddhhmm AS "Timestamp", ifnull(sub.count, ?) AS "Active Services"
FROM static_time 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT static_time.yyyymmddhhmm AS yyyymmddhhmm, count(DISTINCT activations.id) AS count
    FROM activations, static_time 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT activations.id AS activation_id, movement.actual AS arrived_time
        FROM activations 
        JOIN (
            SELECT calling.sid AS sid, max(calling.id) AS max_calling_id
            FROM calling
            GROUP BY calling.sid
            ) AS xxx 
            ON activations.sid = xxx.sid 
        JOIN movement 
            ON movement.calling_id = xxx.max_calling_id AND movement.activation = activations.id
        ) AS yyy 
        ON yyy.activation_id = activations.id
    WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM movement
        WHERE activations.id = movement.activation AND movement.actual < static_time.yyyymmddhhmm)
        )
    AND yyy.arrived_time >= static_time.yyyymmddhhmm 
    GROUP BY static_time.yyyymmddhhmm 
    ORDER BY static_time.yyyymmddhhmm
    ) AS sub 
        ON sub.yyyymmddhhmm = static_time.yyyymmddhhmm
WHERE static_time.yyyymmddhhmm >= ? AND static_time.yyyymmddhhmm <= ?

PARAMS: (0, '2014-01-01 14:15:00.000000', '2014-01-01 15:10:00.000000')
```